24.04 not showing dialogs correctly
I haven't seen this in 20.04 but here and there, I get a popup dialog with no letters shown - just all empty blocks.  
Has anyone seen this issue and/or have suggestions?

This question is similar to: Can't Read System Fonts After Upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
